# How to draw matches in Opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I have matched two vectors of descriptors of two images:

```
cv::Ptr<BinaryDescriptorMatcher> bdm = BinaryDescriptorMatcher::createBinaryDescriptorMatcher();
std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> >  matches;
float maxDist = 10.0;
bdm->radiusMatch(descr2, descr1, matches, maxDist);
// descr1 from image1, descr2 from image2
std::vector<char> mask(matches.size(), 1);
```

But now I want to draw the found matches from the two images.

This does not work:

```
drawMatches(gmlimg, keylines, walls, keylines1, matches, outImg, cv::Scalar::all(-1), cv::Scalar::all(-1), mask, DrawLinesMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);
```

And this neither:

```
drawLineMatches(gmlimg, keylines, walls, keylines1, matches, outImg, cv::Scalar::all(-1), cv::Scalar::all(-1), mask, DrawLinesMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);
```

Comment: How do you know they aren't working? Which image do you expect the matches to be made in? To me you should try doing `cv::Scalar::all(255, 255, 255)` and you should get white lines. Additionally, you are getting matches from image 2 to 1 but drawing the other way around.(But I don't know if `gmlimg` is image 1 or 2)

Comment: drawLineMatches doesn't work, because matches has to be a std::vector<cv::DMatch>, but mine is std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> >, because radiusMatch needs it like that.

And drawMatches needs kepoints and not keylines.


http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/drawing_functions.html


http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.8/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html

Comment: Isn't that the same reason why `drawMatches` doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, didn't see that, because I only saw keypoints and knew that's why it doesn't work (because I have keylines and not keypoints). But how can I draw matches which are in a std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> > with drawLineMatches or another function?

Comment: I'll give that as an answer ok?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting the matches as `std::vector< std::vector<cv::DMatch> >`, which is what you would use when using `BinaryDescriptorMatcher`, you can draw the matches as follows:

```
std::vector<DMatch> matches_to_draw;
std::vector< std::vector<DMatch> >matches_from_matcher;
std::vector< cv::Keypoint > keypoints_Object, keypoints_Scene; // Keypoints 
// Iterate through the matches from descriptor
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < matches_from_matcher.size(); i++)
{
    if (matches_from_matcher[i].size() >= 1)
    {
      cv::DMatch v = matches[i][0];
      /*
       May be you can add a filtering here for the matches
       Skip it if you want to see all the matches
       Something like this - avg is the average distance between all keypoint pairs
       double difference_for_each_match = fabs(keypoints_Object[v.queryIdx].pt.y
                                         - keypoints_Scene[v.trainIdx].pt.y);
       if( (fabs (avg - difference_for_each_match)) <= 5))
     {
       matches_to_draw.push_back(v);
     }
     */
     // This is for all matches
     matches_to_draw.push_back(v);
    }
}
cv::drawMatches(image, keypoints_Object, walls, keypoints_Scene, matches_to_draw, outImg, cv::Scalar::all(-1), cv::Scalar::all(-1), mask, DrawLinesMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);`
```

The outImg should have the matches and the keypoints drawn.

Let me know if it helps!